# Ubuntu misspellings

Tags: discussion, fun

It seems people just can't figure out how to spell the word "Ubuntu." I've personally seen Ubantu, Ubunut and some others, and others have reported seeing Unubtu and even Uboontu. Because of this, I have been working on something I think you will all enjoy.

No, it isn't a way to prevent these spellings, or some weird Mac OS autocorrect that fixes any typos. What I'm presenting is a collection of avatars to match the misspellings! If this is well-received (which I really hope it is), suggest a misspelling, and I'll make and revise an avatar for it.

Here's what I have so far. Some are weird sizes (the ones I made earlier), but the standard is going to be 800x800. Have fun?

I think that's all I have right now. Vote on your favorite!

Comment: This is great! Although how exactly would you use them?

Comment: @AndroidDev make it your avatar

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has seen it upside down and thought it was called `nfunpn`

Comment: @Oli I think I'll make that next. Should be easy.

Comment: Maybe you could make one for http://askubuntu.com/users/8005/

Comment: Further suggestions: **ubutuna** (a fish, I guess?), **ubunto** (I imagine this as a masked bandit), and **ubunt** (a baseball bat).

Comment: @NathanOsman first two done (decided on toes for ubunto). I'll work on ubunt and then try something for bandits.

Comment: I suggest **Uboontu** - maybe you can put something scary in it because of the "Boo!", like a ghost? Or **Ubonetu**, which could be a penguin skeleton.

Comment: [We Hate Fun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583/259230).

Comment: Please make one for **Ubunntu**, e.g. a bunny looking out of a tophat (which could have an Ubuntu emblem on it).

Comment: @ByteCommander ubunntu is up

Comment: @Zacharee1: U**banana**! ;)

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I'm not sure how it'd be different than ubunut :p

Comment: PSA guys. These misspellings should actually be real, and not just made up on the spot like Ubanana.

Comment: Ubundu http://askubuntu.com/revisions/793604/1

Comment: Ubunty http://askubuntu.com/questions/793524/airtel-data-card-not-detecting-on-ubunty-16-04-tls

Comment: Ubunu http://askubuntu.com/questions/666374/ubunu-not-detecting-windows-10

Comment: Ubunttu http://askubuntu.com/questions/645383/ntldr-is-missing-while-installing-ubunttu

Comment: @Zacharee1, you've got to be the first person who ever posted a meta post, answering it 14 times, each time with a positive score.  :)

Comment: Obuntu  http://askubuntu.com/questions/581405/after-installing-14-04-my-computer-boots-straight-to-windows-7/581774#581774

Comment: To bad this is on Meta; it'd be 'fun' to see your rep going up... :O

Comment: Suggestion: uboatu (boat)

Comment: Suggestion: why not make some for the various Ubuntu flavours ?

Comment: @JonasCz I feel like the misspellings wouldn't really be different.

Comment: But the colors and logos would be. Plus, there's various flavor specific misspellings, such as [lubantu](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=lubantu) or others :-)

Comment: @JonasCz that's just ubantu with an L in front, which is exactly what I meant. If you want to change the background for your own purposes, I can provide the XCF files for editing in GIMP.

Comment: Seen in the wild, especially in France, a variety that probably hangs out [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=featured): ubountu

Comment: I see a lot of `unbuntu`.

Comment: Here's one with **Unbuntu** *and* **Ububuntu**: http://askubuntu.com/questions/797157/macbook-pro-7-1-unbuntu-16-04-slow-boot

Comment: umbunu http://askubuntu.com/questions/797593/installer-always-fails-at-the-start and yet he managed to get it right three other times

Comment: **umbutu/lumbutu** http://askubuntu.com/questions/798393/is-apport-enabled-or-disabled-according-to-the-terminal-response-below

Comment: `buntu` - http://askubuntu.com/questions/823667/high-cpu-usage-buntu-16-04-1

Comment: ununtu: Linux for Catholics - http://askubuntu.com/questions/827073/unable-to-use-ubuntu-in-dual-boot-with-windows-7

Comment: **ubunutu** http://askubuntu.com/questions/833965/multi-os-bootable-usb

Comment: Yeah, you need to make Ubunutu --^

Comment: **Unbuntu** is still missing.

Comment: **Ubuntubu** https://askubuntu.com/users/674229/ubuntubu

Comment: **Ubuntub** (U with a bun and a tub) https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/923981

Answer (score 47):

ubunut, Nutty Nautilus

[image]

Comment: OMG I love this one !

Comment: I make this one so many times... :)

Comment: This is strong ;)

Answer (score 42):

unbootu, when you cancel an upgrade halfway through

[image]

Comment: I had to laugh at this one :)

Comment: My favorite. :D

Comment: Great. Haha :-D

Answer (score 28):

ubunaut, Astro Linux

[image]

Comment: I need ten upvotes for this one

Comment: Can we use these as profile pics? My normal one is so boring, I just stole it from Google, this makes me laugh every time. I will give you credit in my profile too.

Comment: Especially relevant considering Mark Shuttleworth (Ubuntu founder, and current sabdfl) was an astronaut.

Comment: This is the distro of the Mars mission. :-D

Comment: @MarkKirby idk why I didn't see your comment. They're meant as profile pics :p. 1:1 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 24):

ubantu, no Ubuntu for u

[image]

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 20):

ubutuna, something's fishy....

[image]

Answer (score 19):

ubunru, in Soviet Linux ubunru installs you

[image]

Comment: This is neither weak nor strong ;)

Answer (score 17):

ubutnu, the butt of a gnu

[image]

Example:
[image]

Comment: If RMS sees this...

Answer (score 15):

unubtu, the Ubuntu n00b

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu for [nubcakes](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16602/367990)...

Answer (score 15):

nfunpn, don't actually try to read it upside-down

[image]

Comment: It should be a "q" and not a "p": "nfunqn". Otherwise it reads "uduntu" upside down.

Comment: @ByteCommander but then I lose the joke

Comment: What kind of joke is "nfunpn" supposed to be? N Fun Pun?

Answer (score 13):

ubutun, PRESS IT

[image]

> Example: [image]

Answer (score 12):

u**boo**tu, scaaaary

[image]

Comment: You might want to have a go at using [*boon*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/boon) instead of *boo*.

Comment: @terdon like gifting Ubuntu? I can try something.

Comment: Or that Ubuntu is a boon, a gift.

Comment: @terdon that's what I meant :p

Comment: @terdon it's uploaded.

Answer (score 11):

ubunto, have you seen Madagascar?

[image]

Example:
[image]

Comment: +1 because this is what I see everywhere! Seriously, even the English pronunciation does not end with an "o" sound... How can people write Ubunto?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I think the problem mostly happen with non-native English speakers. For example, with an Arabic accent, it's much easier to pronounce it as `Ubunto` than `Ubuntu` even though none of the  phonetics (I think that's what it's called :p) in the Ubuntu word is strange to the Arabic language.

Comment: @Dan non-native speaker here. :D I still believe the o sound is very different from the u sound, but I don't know about Arabic so I trust you on that one.

Answer (score 11):

U**bunn**tu, the Linux for bunnies

[image]

Example:
[image]

Comment: This is Weak ;)

Answer (score 10):

uboontu, a gift

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I would've expected something [like this](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/despicableme/images/f/fd/Ghost_minion.jpeg/revision/latest?cb=20141103222949) for U**boo**ntu. :D

Answer (score 5):

U**bent**u, when your system is a little broken:

[image]

**Sources:**

[image]

[image]